# Pspice error: voltage source and/or inductor loop

Tags: spice, pspice

[image: circuit]

I'm trying to simulate the above circuit in Pspice, but I am getting the error:

```
Voltage source and/or inductor loop involving V_V5
```

I looked it up and it says this will happen if the voltage source (V5) gets a short circuited or connected to an inductor, but it is not!

The netlist:

```
* Schematics Netlist *

I_I1         $N_0001 $N_0002 DC 3A  
R_R1         $N_0002 $N_0003  1  
R_R3         $N_0001 $N_0002  4  
R_R4         0 $N_0001  2  
R_R5         0 $N_0002  2  
I_I2         0 $N_0002 DC 5A  
V_V2         $N_0001 0 5V
V_V5         $N_0003 $N_0003   
R_R2         $N_0001 $N_0003  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is a green line through V5. Also the two junction dots on the terminals don't appear on any other component.

Also, in your netlist,

```
V_V5         $N_0003 $N_0003
```

The same net is connected to both terminals of V5.

This is the definition of a short circuit.

Delete the wire connecting the two terminals of V5.

Answer (score 1):

To quote " if the voltage source (V5) gets a short circuited or connected to an inductor, but it is not!" and why do you say that it is not?

When the circuit starts up, what is the equivalent resistance of the I1?  0 volts flowing 3A  = 0 Ohms.  So V5 **IS** shorted and sees 2 Ohms (R1 + R2).  The current source has variable resistance.

To solve this use .IC (initial condition) or do a sweep start up or similar.  I'm sure there are others that have their favourites.

Comment: Stupid question, but why would it be 0 volts through I1?  I thought it would have 7 Volts, because it is in parallel with R3.

But I tried to do a DC sweep startup, and it's giving me the same error!